# PHP string to locale float

Tags: php, format, locale

I trying to parse `"2,249.90000000"` into a float with local decimals.
I want it to `2249,90000000. (nl_NL, money/eur)`

I have tried multiple solutions like floatval or (float). Because number_format wants a number and not a string.

I didn't find the right solution on SO so, I created a new question, but I'm aware that this question is asked once.

Comment: What is the locale you want?

Comment: @Raptor nl_NL. in this case it is euro. (I will add it to the question)

Comment: is not `2249.90000000`?

Comment: Floats do not track decimal precision. If you need to do that you need to use a special library for decimal precision such as http://brick.io/math/class-Brick.Math.BigDecimal.html or https://github.com/direvus/php-decimal

Comment: @KrisRoofe nope, points are thousand separators here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code, code from the first note of [floatval manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

If you want in `2249,90000000` check **[this demo](https://eval.in/805828)**

```
<?php
var_dump(tofloat("2,249.90000000"));

function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos :
        ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);

    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    }

    return floatval(
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . '.' .
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep+1, strlen($num)))
    );
}
```

Comment: Ran this and got `float(2249.9)`

Comment: @JuanMendes, remove the floatval will result in the string format with same length. If use floatval, here need pad to same length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing my previous answer as it was not correct:

```
$number = '2,249.90000000';
$number = floatval(str_replace(',','', $number)); 
echo $number;
```

Comment: Isn't this going to output 224,990,000,000?

Comment: You are right Juan Mendes, I did not test it... just edited with a easier and working one